# Illegal to have abstract class list in java constructor?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to figure out why the following doesn't seem to work in Java.

Here's the basic abstract class:

```
public abstract class Shape {

}
```

Lets say it has two concrete classes, Circle:

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

}
```

and Square, which has multiple constructors:

```
public class Square extends Shape {

public Square(Shape shape)
{
    // nothing
}

public Square(List<Shape> shapes)
{
    // nothing
}
}
```

Given this code:

```
Circle c = new Circle();
List<Circle> cList = new ArrayList<Circle>();
Square s = new Square(c);
Square s2 = new Square(cList);
```

the last line produces the error:

```
The constructor Square(List<Circle>) is undefined.
```

But I have the constructor in Square which takes the parameter `List<Shape>`, and Circle is a Shape - the constructor that takes a single Shape is fine.  So I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your constructor as :

```
       public Square(List<? extends Shape> shapes)
       {
          // nothing
       }
```

Which means it accepts all classes which extend `Shape`.

Precautionary note: Be aware of the side effects as well which arise because of the same fact i.e. it accepts all classes which extend `Shape`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!  I have been working with Java for a few months but had not yet seen the wildcard type parameter before.

Answer (score 0):

> But I have the constructor in Square which takes the parameter List, and Circle is a Shape - the constructor that takes a single Shape is fine.

That's because of the fact that generic types are invariant in Java. We know `Circle` is-a `Shape` but still `List<Circle>` is-not-a `List<Shape>`, so you cannot substitute `List<Circle>` with `List<Shape>`. To fill this gap you have to use bounded wildcards as pointed out by @Yogendra.

You can find an explanation [here](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/java-generics-tutorial-part-ii.html).